# What is the best way to improve performance of data driven subscriptions in SQL Reporting Services?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm required to deliver thousands of emailed reports each day to support business operations. Currently I use SQL Server Reporting Services to implement this. Though SSRS is very stable and reliable, it also seems to be slow for my particular use case, taking 30+ minutes to complete some of the data driven subscriptions.

Data driven subscriptions offers us the opportunity to store a T-SQL query within the report server that selects the email addresses we want to send to along with the parameters we want to feed into the report and set that to run on a schedule. This is useful because it allows us to select the division, currency, and other parameters that personalize the report in the best way for the recipient. However, even a report with a few parameters, there are a finite, small number of permutations. For example, for one report that we use to send 10k emails each day, there are only 12 permutations sent daily. What I would really like is to preload a cache with those 12 permutations.

SSRS allows you to cache a report. I turned this on and left the default 30 minutes in and it seemed to have zero effect when run with a data driven subscription. In other words, I ran the subscription, which send about 950 emails with caching off and then with caching on and the run time for the subscription was identical -- it had no impact.

I've also attempted to use snapshots, which sounds like it would be perfect. Unfortunately, snapshots only work with default parameter values. It seems like there is no way to store snapshots with each permutation of possible parameter values -- THIS IS WHAT I THINK I WANT. Emailing thousands of reports from the already assembled snapshots should speed things up quite a lot.

Has anyone found any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it feasible for you to reduce the numbers of rows in the view behind the data-driven subscription?

for example instead of

```
to: joe@abc.com   parameter1:55
to: billy@abc.com parameter1:55
to: bob@abc.com   parameter1:66`
```

it would be

```
bcc: joe@abc.com, billy@abc.com parameter1:55
bcc: bob@abc.com                parameter1:66
```

I think it's better to look for ways to avoid generating 10k times the same files than to optimise performance trough caching etc. If you can't do it like above, i would try to have ssrs generate the files you need and then handle the emailing outside subscriptions.

Comment: Yeah, we could do that -- or similarly use email distribution lists. We were just making sure there isn't a way to handle it all inside the report server before going that route.

Comment: Dropping the files and then using SSIS to pick them up and email them would be a way of going with your second idea. It's probably doable but means extra pieces -- it's certainly an option to consider though at this point I am leaning towards using distribution lists. Thanks for your response.